# Are stretch marks normal?

Tags: weightlifting, workout

I'm an 18 year old athlete, 210 lbs. I work out a lot, working on gaining strength and muscle. After a really intense workout I'll get stretch marks along some of the areas that I worked such as biceps. Is this normal? Should I be worried or are these common for anyone who does intense weight training? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should put moisturiser on them regularly. You don't want to be left with big scars(like me). The earlier you start the better.

Comment: You won't get stretch marks from a single weightlifting session. Your skin is elastic enough to handle that. Stretch marks are from long term, rapid gain in weight/height (Such as a pregnancy, growth spurt, etc) and are a result of tearing in the skin. You can get them over time, and you may be noticing them after a session, but a single session doesn't create them.

Comment: But its valid to say that after a single session some become more pronounced?  @JohnP

Comment: Oh, yes, they can definitely become more noticeable as there is more blood in the vessels near the skin. That is != to causing them, though. :)

Comment: Stretch marks seem quite common to me. I see quite a few bodybuilder a have stretch marks on their upper biceps and ass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is this normal?**

**Yes**, it is normal.

**Should I be worried or are these common for anyone who does intense weight training?**

**No**, you do not need to worry about it. Good news is that **these stretch mark will disappear after some time**.

Here are some article regarding the causes of stretch marks :-

[Mayoclinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/stretch-marks/basics/causes/con-20032624)

> Stretch marks sometimes occur **during substantial weight gain**. Weightlifters can develop stretch marks, particularly on the arms.

[NHS Choices](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Stretch-marks/Pages/Causes.aspx)

> You may get stretch marks if you put on **a lot of weight over a short period of time**. The stretch marks sometimes remain even after losing weight, but **should eventually fade**.Bodybuilders and athletes can also get **stretch marks as their muscles increase in size**.

Here are some methods on how to reduce them (if you are too concern about it) :-

[Reducing stretch mark](http://www.top10homeremedies.com/how-to/how-to-get-rid-of-stretch-marks-fast.html)

With that said, I have a stretch mark on both of my biceps, where the right side is almost gone whereas the left side has slowly started to fade. And some on my left shoulder.

Comment: Would you mind writing up the important parts of the links? It's usually the way to go because links die with time, which would render this answer very empty later.

Answer (score -8):

Stretch marks are common and completely harmless. It happens when the skin extends due to the fast growth of the skin's underlying tissues. Stretch marks gradually decline and turn white as they recover.

Gaining a lot of weight in a short period puts strain on your skin, which has to stretch to accommodate the extra body mass. Depending on where you gain excess weight, stretch marks might appear on the body.

To prevent putting unnecessary strain on your skin, it is advisable to lose or gain weight gradually.

Rapid muscle mass growth during weight training and bodybuilding can stretch your skin and generate stretch marks.

You may not be able to eliminate your stretch marks 100%, but some [home treatments](https://prohealthblogger.info/stretch-marks/how-to-get-rid-of-stretch-marks-20-effective-home-remedies-to-treat-stretch-marks/) can help fade stretch marks significantly.

Though there is no magical diet that will instantly remove your stretch marks, certain nutrients can enhance skin health and lessen the appearance of stretch marks. Protein, Vitamins A, C, and D, and Zinc are a few examples.

If home remedies do not significantly improve the appearance of your stretch marks, consult a physician for therapy.

They may advocate for adequate hydration, diet, and skincare.

Comment: Eliza - Welcome to the site! I believe that because your answer links to (presumably) your own site, it is being flagged as spam. I invite you to read the about page and the help pages, with attention to [self promotion](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). You have a decent answer here, but it's getting flagged by other users as spam for the link inclusion. I hope this helps!